# Filter results from distinct count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cte

I need to modify a procedure to make **statistics** on my database.

I got a temporary table which contains all the data that I need to make those statistics.
It contains all the relevant actions *FormIdNb* of the working units *NumCavalier* in one day :

```
-- Every action from all units will be stored in this temp table
-- DateHeure = Time of action
-- NumCavalier = ID of working unit
-- FormIdNb = Action type
CREATE TABLE #tmp_DailyMissions (
DateHeure datetime,
NumCavalier  nchar(3),
FormIdNb int
)

INSERT INTO #tmp_DailyMissions
SELECT        DateHeure, Cavalier.NumCavalier, FormIdNb
FROM            ECN4, Cavalier
WHERE        (DateHeure BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime) AND (Cavalier.Terminal = @terminal) AND (Cavalier.NumCavalier = ECN4.NumCavalier)
```

This temporary table will store all actions that all the working units made in one entire day (just as a logging system).
The significant values for *FormIdNb* are :

> *FormIdNb* > 3 ==> The working unit was active
>   *FormIdNb* = 3 ==> The working unit was idle
>   *FormIdNb* < 3 ==> The working unit was inactive

The request that I got right now (Thanks to @AndriyM), returns the number of working units who were *ACTIVE*, *IDLE* and *INACTIVE* on each interval of time of the day (15min) :

```
WITH time_cte(StartTime, EndTime) AS
  (
    SELECT
      StartTime = @starttime,
      EndTime   = DATEADD(mi, 15, @starttime)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      EndTime,
      DATEADD(mi, 15, EndTime)
    FROM
      time_cte
    WHERE
      EndTime < @EndTime
  )
SELECT
  t.StartTime,
  ActiveUnitCount   = COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN d.FormIdNb > 3 THEN d.NumCavalier END)),
  IdleUnitCount     = COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN d.FormIdNb = 3 THEN d.NumCavalier END)),
  InactiveUnitCount = COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN d.FormIdNb < 3 THEN d.NumCavalier END))
FROM
  time_cte AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmp_DailyMissions AS d
    ON d.DateHeure >= t.StartTime
    AND d.DateHeure < t.EndTime
GROUP BY
  t.StartTime
;
```

The problem is, as I said above, that the temporary table I use store the data as a logging system.
This means that it can contain, for a working unit on a same interval of time, **any value** of *FormIdNb*.
For example : 1 row *FormIdNb* = 2, 1 row *FormIdNb* = 3 and 1 row *FormIdNb* = 4.

**My question is :**
How to make a request who get rid of irrelevant values ?

**More precisely :**
If a working unit was *ACTIVE*, but was also *IDLE* and/or *INACTIVE* on an interval of time, how to "remove" this working unit from the *IDLE* and *INACTIVE* counts, and only keep the maximum value of *FormIdNb* for each intervals of time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Scott Hodgin, you essentially want to consider *MAX(FormIdNb)* instead of just *FormIdNb*, and count the results based on whether the MAX result is greater than, equal to or less than 3.

Adding a correlated subquery to the joining condition, as Scott is suggesting, would be one way.

Another would be to use a derived table to first get the max *FormIdNb* per *NumCavalier* and range:

```
SELECT
  t.StartTime,
  d.NumCavalier,
  MaxFormIdNb = MAX(d.FormIdNb)
FROM
  time_cte AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmp_DailyMissions AS d
    ON d.DateHeure >= t.StartTime
    AND d.DateHeure < t.EndTime
GROUP BY
  t.StartTime,
  d.NumCavalier
```

and only then get the counts. This is the whole query:

```
WITH time_cte(StartTime, EndTime) AS
  (
    SELECT
      StartTime = @starttime,
      EndTime   = DATEADD(mi, 15, @starttime)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      EndTime,
      DATEADD(mi, 15, EndTime)
    FROM
      time_cte
    WHERE
      EndTime < @EndTime
  )
SELECT
  StartTime,
  ActiveUnitCount   = COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxFormIdNb > 3 THEN d.NumCavalier END),
  IdleUnitCount     = COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxFormIdNb = 3 THEN d.NumCavalier END),
  InactiveUnitCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxFormIdNb < 3 THEN d.NumCavalier END)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.StartTime,
      d.NumCavalier,
      MaxFormIdNb = MAX(d.FormIdNb)
    FROM
      time_cte AS t
      LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmp_DailyMissions AS d
        ON d.DateHeure >= t.StartTime
        AND d.DateHeure < t.EndTime
    GROUP BY
      t.StartTime,
      d.NumCavalier
  ) AS s
GROUP BY
  t.StartTime
;
```

Note that it is now just *COUNT(...)*, not *COUNT(DISTINCT ...)*, because the derived table produces only distinct *NumCavalier* values anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, I'm missing something, but it sounds like to want the max(formidnb) for each NumCavalier in the time slice you're processing.  I haven't fully syntax checked this, but I think you could add the following to just above your semicolon

```
AND d.FormIdNb = 
(
select MAX(FormIdNb) 
FROM #tmp_DailyMissions
WHERE NumCavalier = d.NumCavalier and
DateHeure >= t.StartTime
AND DateHeure < t.EndTime
)
```